# Check if given latitude and longitude is on the ploygon using in laravel controller

Tags: laravel-7

I have a tabel named Zone, there i have fields like id, zone_id,name,polygon. this data gets from traccar geofences. its stroes data correctly. now i need to find a given latitude and logitude in the range of polygon i got.
for example:
given points = $x = 26.421813284735137; $y =  43.9439818756710;
x is latitude and y is logitude.
polygon = POLYGON((26.421813284735137 43.94398187567106, 26.386908685914406 43.887332873404816, 26.153830842116705 43.957312477351465, 26.04340357033719 43.956808679085405, 26.01138700233561 43.98673788705223, 26.053647026517794 44.07652551095268, 26.262162148604205 44.08222631247017, 26.428194745096604 44.01096629350155, 26.421813284735137 43.94398187567106))
i am using laravel 7. i need to find it in the controller.

Comment: any solutions, help me out

Comment: please help me ,i dont get any solutions

Comment: please help me ,i dont get any solutions

Comment: Found any solution ? or need ?